# SVG element has too much extra space

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using Bootstrap 4, and I have a simple `svg` element in my Web page:

```
<svg>
    <polygon points="0,0 20,5 0,10" style="fill: black; stroke: black;" />
    <polygon points="20,0 40,5 20,10" style="fill: black; stroke: black;" />
</svg>
```

And to show how much extra space the element is using, I created a border around the element:

```
<style>
    svg {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

The graphic is very simple, and displays mostly as it should, like this:

[image: svg screenshot]

But I don't understand why there is so much extra whitespace on the right and bottom. I've tried everything I can think of to just make the container fit to the actual content: adding `viewBox="0 0 20 40"` to the `svg` tag just blows up the graphic so that it's enormous, and `viewPort` doesn't do anything. I've tried a bunch of other CSS "tricks" and putting the graphic inside its own `div` element, all of which had no effect on the appearance of the graphic.

I don't remember experiencing this issue before. Does Bootstrap add extra styling to `svg` graphics that I have to override, or is this normal? Appreciate any help on how to fix it.

Comment: you can fix this issue by giving width and height for your SVG element I think.

Comment: Do you create this with Adoce illustrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an inline replaced element has no width nor height explicitely set, it will default to 300px * 150px. *(Actual rules are [specified here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width))*

Are concerned by this rule, <iframe> <video> <canvas> and **<svg>**.

To avoid that, set a width or height on your <svg> (eitehr through its attributes, or through CSS.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <polygon points="0,0 20,5 0,10" style="fill: black; stroke: black;" />
    <polygon points="20,0 40,5 20,10" style="fill: black; stroke: black;" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

As Kaiido mentions you need to declare a viewBox attribute for the svg element. To calculate the size of the viewBox I use to wrap everything in a `<g>` element and use the method `getBBox()` for that `<g>` element.

In this case the method returns the following bounding box: `{x:0,y:0,height:40,width:10}`.

The viewbox you need is: `viewBox="0 0 40 10"`.

Since your polygons have a stroke you need some extra space so I used `viewBox="-1 -1 42 12"`

You don't need to keep the `<g id="test">` wrap.

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-1 -1 42 12">
  <g id="test">
    <polygon points="0,0 20,5 0,10" style="fill: black; stroke: black;" />
    <polygon points="20,0 40,5 20,10" style="fill: black; stroke: black;" />
  </g>
</svg>
```